# Can't locate file despite given path

Tags: file, svn, path, directory, phpunit

I have a problem with the path of a certain file. I want to include a file in my phpunit test. In our central repository it is located here:

```
include 'secure\functions.php';
```

However I get an error while running the test claiming that a certain function that I am calling within the test, that is located in this included file, is undefined or that the directory doens't exist:

"Warning: include(secure\functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\PVT\root\tests\unit-test\testFunctions\testFunctions.php on line 3"

"Fatal error: Call to undefined function checkbrute()"

When I include the whole path to the file like this, then it works fine. OBS this is when it is checked out and running locally:

```
include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\PVT\root\secure\functions.php';
```

The problem is that I am going to committ this to our central repo so that anybody can execute the tests hence my local path won't be valid for someone else. Any ideas on what could be wrong? Why isn't the first option working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the absolute file path.  As you can see from your question, your code is looking in the wrong place for your file:

`C:\xampp\htdocs\PVT\root\tests\unit-test\testFunctions\testFunctions.php`
vs `C:\xampp\htdocs\PVT\root\secure\functions.php`

I use Linux, and I'm not sure if this would work in Windows, but try referencing the current/main directory the project is in, a la `./secure/functions.php` if it were Linux.